# Generate Identity from bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to take a Bearer Token string and convert it to the `Identity` object manually in asp.net?

Cheers,
Aziz

Comment: Could you explain more? how you take Bearer Token? Via simple post or get method? And do you want authorize caller by that token?

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari I have a <a> tag so it would be a GET endpoint and I would like to authorize that the user is who they claim

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old question, but I think answer was still missing. I was able to regenerate Principal by using the following line

```
var ticket = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(accessToken);
var identity = ticket.Identity;
```

Answer (score 1):

The token just holds claims and it's just used for authentication into the resource. If one of those claims held user information you could create an identity and assign the claims to it.

```
public void ValidateBearerToken(OwinContext context)
{
    try
    {
       var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
       byte[] securityKey = GetBytes("some key"); //this should come from a config file

       SecurityToken securityToken;

       var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
       {
          ValidAudience = "http://localhost:2000", 
          IssuerSigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(securityKey),
          ValidIssuer = "Self"
       };

       var auth = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(auth) && auth.Contains("Bearer"))
       {
          var token = auth.Split(' ')[1];

          var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);

          context.Request.User = principal;
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       var message = ex.Message;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? How do I go from string (raw token) to extracting info.

Comment: This will validate your token and set up the claims principle. You would then just add claims to the pricinple.Claims list.

Comment: I am using SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and not a Jwt security token

Answer (score 1):

First you need to crate some claims based on token then create `ClaimsIdentity` and use it to authorize the user.

```
public ActionResoult Login(string token)
{
    if(_tokenManager.IsValid(token))         
    {
        // optionally you have own user manager which returns roles and user name from token
        // no matter how you store users and roles
        var user=_myUserManager.GetUserRoles(token);

        // user is valid, going to authenticate user for my App
        var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
            new[] 
            {  
                // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, token),
                new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),

                // an optional claim you could omit this 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),

                // populate assigned user's role form your DB 
                // and add each one as a claim  
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Roles[0]),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Roles[1]),
                // and so on
            },
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Identity is sign in user based on claim don't matter 
        // how you generated it             
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);

        // auth is succeed, just from a token
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction"); 
    }
    // invalid user        
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "We could not authorize you :(");
    return View();
}
```

Now you could use `Authorize` filter as well:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
}

// since we injected user roles to Identity we could do this as well
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    // since we injected our authentication mechanism to Identity pipeline 
    // we have access current user principal by calling also
    // HttpContext.User
}
```

Also I encourage you to have look [Token Based Authentication Sample](https://github.com/samfgl/TokenBasedAuthenticationSample) from my github repo as a very simple working example.

Comment: There is no _myUserManager.GetUserRoles(token);... method. I am using the public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider - Does that help?

Comment: `_myUserManager` is an example. To show how you can use own classes to generate claims and sign in users based on. In this example I used `_myUserManager` to extract current users roles you could implement your very own classes. Username and roles just simple string. And optional if you don't have username or roles. If you look at my github repo you could see how I used just a single string to authorize users.

Comment: I do not have a current user context. I need to go from string token to the user. I need to know how the locic inside _myUserManager.GetUserRoles(token);

Comment: So how you store your users data? In DB? And are your users have roles?

Comment: I use the default aspnet_user table. However the token generation is handled by a Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth; nuget. Tokens are not stored in the db so i can not just pull the reference to the user.

Comment: If I am understating you right. You implemented an OAuth server and you want your user authorize from the server then server sends a token for each authorized users. Am I right? If so first time you must create a user and then assign this token to the user. Use `UserManager.CreateAsync()` method to create new user and `UserManager.AddLoginAsync()` to assign token to the user. then second time you just need to call `SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync()` with same token. If you need detailed instruction tell me. I will add some sample code.